# How to read the contents of Blobs using Azure Storage SDK for Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I've added the Azure package to my Anaconda distribution and also installed the Azure Storage SDK for Python.  I'm attempting to read the files already uploaded to a specific blob container using:

```
from azure.storage import BlobService
blob_service = BlobService(account_name='azure subscription name',   
account_key='azure subscription key')

blobs = []
marker = None
while True:
   batch = blob_service.list_blobs('vrc', marker=marker, prefix='VRC_')
  blobs.extend(batch)
  if not batch.next_marker:
    break
  marker = batch.next_marker
for blob in blobs:
print(blob.name)
```

When I run this script, I receive the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'azure.storage'
```

How do I resolve this issue so that I can read the text files and PDFs in my blob container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure how you installed the storage sdk, or what version you're using, but you should just need to do the following:

Install:

```
pip install azure-storage
```

Import and instantiate blob service:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name="<storagename>",account_key="<storagekey>")
```

At that point, you should be able to list blobs (or download blobs, or whatever else you need to do).

Comment: I downloaded the storage SDK from Github using git at the command line.  I then ran pip install azure-storage.  I tried installing it using Anaconda, but the package was not available, just the Azure package.

Comment: `azure-storage` requires cryptography. If you are using linux, you need to also do this:

https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#building-cryptography-on-linux

Comment: How do we read the contents of the blob ? like a file stream ?

Comment: @RamMehta - that's a completely separate question. I suggest posting a new question, along with the specific issue(s) you're having.

Answer (score 2):

This is old question but become relevant due to latest deprecation of some code blocks in SDK.

Please follow the below to get list of blob files in a given container with modified date too.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
storageconnectionstring='yourstorageconnectionstring'
blobclient=BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(storageconnectionstring)
containerclient=blobclient.get_container_client('yourblobcontainername')
for blobs in containerclient.list_blobs():
    print (blobs['name'],": Modified: ",blobs['last_modified'])
```